# Is it possible to resolve SC2001 ("See if you can use ${variable//search/replace} instead") while using a position variable?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion, shellcheck

I'm looking for a one liner to replace any character in a variable string at a variable position with a variable substitute.  I came up with this working solution:

```
echo "$string" | sed "s/./${replacement}/${position}"
```

An example usage:

```
string=aaaaa
replacement=b
position=3
echo "$string" | sed "s/./${replacement}/${position}"
aabaa
```

Unfortunately, when I run shellcheck with a script which contains my current solution it tells me:

```
SC2001: See if you can use ${variable//search/replace} instead.
```

I'd like to use parameter expansion like it's suggesting instead of piping to sed, but I'm unclear as to the proper formatting when using a position variable.  The [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) doesn't seem to discuss positioning within strings at all.

Is this possible?

Comment: The "working solution" doesn't work in general.  Test with `replacement='&'` and `replacement=/`.  See [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/4154375).

Comment: @pjh, yes -- I was very explicit in comment discussion (now removed apparently) preceding the answer that it was not in any way a general-case solution; the OP indicated that it was adequate for their use case, and requested that the commented suggestion be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash doesn't have a general-case replacement for all sed facilities (the shellcheck [wiki page for warning SC2001](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2001) acknowledges as much), but in some specific scenarios -- including the case posed -- parameter expansions can be combined to achieve the desired effect:

```
string=aaaaa
replacement=b
position=3
echo "${string:0:$(( position - 1 ))}${replacement}${string:position}"
```

Here, we're splitting the value up into substrings: `${string:0:$(( position - 1 ))}` is the text preceding the content to be replaced, and `${string:position}` is the text following that point.

Comment: The expression for the new string is correct, but it can be simplified to `${string:0:position-1}${replacement}${string:position}`.

Comment: It's not relevant to the substance of the question, but the `echo` command doesn't work in general.  Test with `string=nn ; replacement=- ; position=1`.